# Javascript Date different result between Internet Explorer And Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

My problem about creating new Date object on javascript. 
When I create `new Date` object results as below:

[Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3KUY.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHktk.png)

Yes I'm aware timezones different. Same URL path, same page, only browser different.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Are those in the same computer?

Comment: I don't see any difference aside from the timezone. This results in a timestamp being interpreted differently.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the same dates. Explorer seems to be an hour ahead (GMT+0300), and is displaying Nov 1, 00:00:00. Chrome is an hour behind (GMT+0200), so it's displaying Oct 31, 23:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the time zone. You are creating these dates when the time zones are different for those browsers.